# XSLT: Avoiding indentation in some nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, indentation

I have some XSLT that replaces linebreaks with `<Break/>` tags and it works fine as long as there isn't multiple consecutive linebreaks. I think it's the `indent="yes"` that's causing problems.
Can it be disabled for some nodes?

Basically nodes with mixed content (text and elements) can not contain any linebreaks.

The input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Account xmlns="http://example.com/account">
    <Owner>
        <ID>012345789</ID>
        <Name>Peter Johnson</Name>
    </Owner>
    <Notes>
        <NoteID>012345789</NoteID>
        <Text>This is the description:
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

Line 4, after double linebreak
Line 5</Text>
    </Notes>
</Account>
```

The XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://example.com/account" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template name="replace_sab">
    <!-- with string s, replace substring a by string b -->
    <!-- s, a and b are parameters determined upon calling  -->
    <xsl:param name="s" />
    <xsl:param name="a" />
    <xsl:param name="b" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($s,$a)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($s,$a)" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="$b" />
            <xsl:call-template name="replace_sab">
                <xsl:with-param name="s" select="substring-after($s,$a)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="a" select="$a" />
                <xsl:with-param name="b" select="$b" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$s" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()[boolean(normalize-space())]">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace_sab">
        <xsl:with-param name="s" select="." />
        <xsl:with-param name="a" select="'&#xA;'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="b"><Break/></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output that I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Account xmlns="http://example.com/account">
    <Owner>
        <ID>012345789</ID>
        <Name>Peter Johnson</Name>
    </Owner>
    <Notes>
        <NoteID>012345789</NoteID>
        <Text>This is the description:<Break/>Line 1<Break/>Line 2<Break/>Line 3<Break/>
            <Break/>Line 4, after double linebreak<Break/>Line 5</Text>
    </Notes>
</Account>
```

The output I would like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Account xmlns="http://example.com/account">
    <Owner>
        <ID>012345789</ID>
        <Name>Peter Johnson</Name>
    </Owner>
    <Notes>
        <NoteID>012345789</NoteID>
        <Text>This is the description:<Break/>Line 1<Break/>Line 2<Break/>Line 3<Break/><Break/>Line 4, after double linebreak<Break/>Line 5</Text>
    </Notes>
</Account>
```

I am using "TIBCO XSLT 1.0" XSLT engine in a Tibco BusinessWorks process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard way of doing this.

If you were using Saxon you could use the saxon:suppress-indentation output parameter, which becomes a standard option in XSLT 3.0.

Perhaps you could find a way of inserting the Saxon serializer into your processing pipeline even if you stick with the Tibco XSLT engine.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the case. The solution will probably end up being `indent="no"` and live with a one-liner XML string as output.

Comment: +1 from me, if I could give more i would :). This allows a workaround for FrameMaker 2015 bugs that adds whitespace in a non-deterministic manner when reading DITA files.